# How to post username from html inline form

Tags: php, html, drupal

Hey I have a form I am posting, how can I send the user name using the drupal variables

```
 <input type="hidden" name="user[name]" value="user"/>
```

How can I change the value to be the user name using the drupal variables?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite get what you are trying to do.

If you want it to be in form variables you have to describe them in a form and submit it properly:

```
$form['user'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 'user',
);
```

And get it like this in submit function:

```
$user = $form_state['values']['user'];
```

If you need to describe input in html you can get it in submit function by simple:

```
$user=$_POST['user'];
```

Maybe you want to use:

```
variable_set('user', $user);
```

it stores variable in sessions or something and you can access it in any place in your page by:

```
$user = variable_get('user');
```

it is deleted by:

```
variable_del('user');
```